# Translation of "My colleagues have never been to Europe"

Tags: grammar, verb-endings

I've recently come back to Korean after a (fairly) long break and I'm surprised by how much I've forgotten. I got back into some vocab word lists and making sentences with them. I had a few questions about some of my sentences and grammar I made with the words:

Quick note on how I write: If something is in brackets with some fwd-slash separated suffixes, it means I don't know which one would be most appropriate (And why!!)

```
동료 - colleague
My colleagues have never been to Europe:
my attempt: 내 동료들 아무도 유럽에(게?) 가고 ( 않아 / 없(는데/어?)?) 
Naver: 내 동료 중 아무도 유럽에 가본 적이 없다. (whats is 중, 가*본*, 적이(Enemy)?)
```

This sentence by Naver Translate really confused me because it introduced to me a whole lot of new words and I have no idea what they mean (and Naver Translate didn't help me either). If you know what those little additions mean and why they're used instead of my vocab, I'd love to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My colleagues did not go to Europe recently

내 동료들은 최근에 유럽에 가지 않았다.

My colleagues have never been to Europe

내 동료들은 유럽에 가본 적이 없다. (That is, **have + been** checks the experience in all their born days)

@동료들 중 아무도 = anybody among colleagues

@@적=experience : 가본 적=간 적=간 경험=갔었던 경험=experience that they have gone.

@@@본 :

1) 나는 바나나를 먹어본 적이 없다 (=먹은 적이 없다=먹지 않았다) I did not eat banana

Here 본=적=먹다. If we omit 본, then it is fine. So 본 may be an emphsis.

2) 본 프로그램(=이 프로그램)은 중요하다. This program is important.

http://dic.daum.net/word/view.do?wordid=kkw000114065&supid=kku000141974

Answer (score 2):

한국어 동사 + 보다 -> 그러한 움직임을 경험하다(Someone experienced something.) = have + past participle of the verb

~한 적이 있다 -> there were times or a time when someone did something

가봤다 = 가본 적이 있다 = 간 적이 있다 = have been

가보지 않았다 = 가본 적이 없다 = 간 적이 없다 = have not been

My colleagues have never been to Europe.
내 동료들은 유럽에 가본 적이 없다. (= 내 동료들은 유럽에 지금까지 한 번도 가지 않았다.)

My colleagues never went to Europe.
내 동료들은 유럽에 가지 않았다. (= 내 동료들은 과거 어느 때에 유럽에 가지 않았다. 그 때 이전이나 그 때 이후에 갔는지 안 갔는지는 알 수 없다.)

The Naver translation is a bad Korean sentence.
You can not trust on-line translation.
So I corrected the mistakes of the Naver sentence.

내 동료들중 유럽에 가본 사람은 아무도 없다. None of my colleagues have been to Europe. (= 내 동료들은 유럽에 가본 적이 없다. My colleagues have never been to Europe.)

Comment: Welcome to KSE. I hope that activities in here will be joyful.